# Difference between hosted mode and development mode

Tags: gwt

What is the difference between hosted mode and development mode in GWT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hosted mode is the old name for development mode, they're the same.

There are two modes, and they're currently named development mode and 
production mode

Development mode runs Java whereas production  mode compiles to JavaScript.

This means that in Development mode you're using the true java.lang.String or 
java.util.ArrayList for instance, whereas in production mode it's the 
emulated version that's being used.

It sometimes lead to different results (Java's Date is quite not the same as JavaScript's one)

Comment: And GWT 2.5.0-rc1 just added a new mode: super dev mode, where code is compiled to JS but still is dedicated to dev. https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/superdevmode